# Plot a sequence to show the limit, improving the code

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, code

I wanted to generate a good figure to show the visual definition for the limit of a sequence. This is an idea so far, but I would like to improve it, for example:

- How can I delete the thicks on the $x$ and $y$ axes? I mean the numbers. The $\ell \pm \epsilon$ are fine.
- How can I make the $x$ axis longer, in order to get a larger figure?

Thank you! This is the code, with the preamble.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, left=23mm, top=23mm, right=23mm, bottom=23mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bb=stixtwo]{mathalpha}

\usepackage{concmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage{pspicture}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
\ifmmode%
\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
\else
 \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
\fi}
\tikzset{box around/.style={
draw,rounded corners,
inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,
node contents={},fit=#1
},      
}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[black, thick, 
 ymin = 0,
 ymax = 3,
 xmin = 0,
 xmax = 19,
 axis x line=center,
 axis y line=left]
\addplot[samples at={0,...,16},only marks,mark size=1, blue]{(2*x+1)/(x+2)};
\end{axis}
 \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0) -- (6.85, 0)
node[right] {$n$};
\draw[thick, dashed] (0, 3.3) -- (6, 3.3);
\draw[thick, dashed] (0, 4.3) -- (6, 4.3);
 \draw[thick, dotted] (0, 3.8) -- (6, 3.8);
\coordinate (A) at (0, 3.3);
  \draw (A) node[left] {$\ell - \epsilon$} node {};
     \coordinate (B) at (0, 4.3);
  \draw (B) node[left] {$\ell + \epsilon$} node {};
 \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0) -- (0, 5.7)
node[above] {$a_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Just to note that the `tikzmark` package provides a more sophisticated version of your `\tikznode` command, called `\tikzmarknode`.  For example, it does better handling of math modes.  Just put `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` in your preamble and then you're good to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code (I dont have revisited Your preamble):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{total={173mm, 257mm}, left=23mm, top=23mm, right=23mm, bottom=23mm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bb=stixtwo]{mathalpha}

\usepackage{concmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage{pspicture}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}
\tikzset{box around/.style={
        draw,rounded corners,
        inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,
        node contents={},fit=#1
    },      
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[black, thick, 
                ymin = 0,
                ymax = 3,
                xmin = 0,
                xmax = 25,
                axis x line=center,
                axis y line=left,
                hide x axis,
                hide y axis]
                \addplot[samples at={0,...,23},only marks,mark size=1, blue]{(2*x+1)/(x+2)};
            \end{axis}
            \draw[->,  black] (0, 0) -- (6.85, 0)
            node[right] {$n$};
            \draw[thick, dashed] (0, 3.3) -- (6.5, 3.3);
            \draw[thick, dashed] (0, 4.3) -- (6.5, 4.3);
            \draw[thick, dotted] (0, 3.8) -- (6.5, 3.8);
            \coordinate (A) at (0, 3.3);
            \draw (A) node[left] {$\ell - \epsilon$} node {};
            \coordinate (B) at (0, 4.3);
            \draw (0,3.8) node[left] () {$\ell$};
            \draw (B) node[left] {$\ell + \epsilon$} node {};
            \draw[->, thick, black] (0, 0) -- (0, 5.7)
            node[above] {$a_n$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Simpler solution only with `tikz`.
Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=.5cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \draw[-latex]   (-.5,0) -- (5.1,0) node[right] {$n$};
        \draw[-latex]   (0,-.5) -- (0,3.1) node[above] {$a_n$};
        \node at (-.2,-.2) (o) {$O$};
        \draw[thin,dashed] (5,2.3)--(0,2.3) node[left] () {$\ell+\epsilon$};
        \draw[thick,dashed] (5,2)--(0,2) node[left] () {$\ell$};
        \draw[thin,dashed] (5,1.7)--(0,1.7) node[left] () {$\ell-\epsilon$};
        \foreach \x in {0,...,30}
        \fill[blue] ({\x/6},{(2*\x+1)/(\x+2)}) circle(1pt); 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is amazing, thank you!

Comment: @Henry I have only completed Your solution. For my taste, for graph only, I propose another simpler solution, only with tikz. See my edit.

Comment: Wow, the other solution looks so elegant! Thank you!